# css div positioned absolute not expanding all the way to the bottom

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use a absolute div as my background (only on certain pages..I can not use body for this purpose)

However I am not able to expand it to the bottom of page. Pleas help.

Black background is only to the middle of page. Notice in my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/z9Unk/317/

CSS

```
.background {
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index:-1;
  background:black;   
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
}

.item {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="background">
    Hover Me
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="item">
   </div>
    <div class="item">
   </div>
    <div class="item">
   </div>
    <div class="item">
   </div>
    <div class="item">
   </div>
    <div class="item">
   </div>
    <div class="item">
   </div>
    <div class="item">
   </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is `position: fixed`, not `position: absolute`. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/z9Unk/321/).

Alternatively, why not just set the `background-color` of your `<body>`?

Comment: I mentioned in my note above that I want different background on different pages. thanks for yout help.

Answer (score 3):

Use `position: fixed;`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/z9Unk/322/

```
.background {
  position:fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index:-1;
  background:black;   
}
```

If you wish to still use `position: absolute;` you will need set the `body` to `position: relative;`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/z9Unk/324/

```
body {
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I can not use body for this purpose

Why not?

Just add a different class or id to the body element of each page and define your different backgrounds/ background-images in the CSS code!

You are using presentational markup which is semantically not correct.

PS: Here is a link FYI [**The Motive Web Design Glossary**](http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/markup.php)

Comment: hmm....let me understand this more....I am not sure what is presentational markup...thanks for tip...

Comment: just one question...you will not do what I am doing in production...is it that bad????...

Comment: @user2384694: Yes, I wouldn't do it. You never should use HTML elements in your markup that are not needed for the semantical structure of your content. Or in other words: Do not add elements to your HTML markup that are only for presentational purposes (which only serve the optics). Due to some browser bugs or other shortcomings in CSS support there are some exceptions (just a few). Your case is none of them ...! ;-)